# Zeros of incomplete exponential functions

Tags: cv.complex-variables, nt.number-theory

Let
$$ f_N(z) = \sum_{n=N}^\infty \frac{z^n}{n!},$$
where $N$ is a positive integer.

> Where are the (complex) zeros of those functions located?

It would be sufficient for me to know what the smallest (in absolute value) non-zero zeros are for a general $N$. Maybe an approximation of those zeros would also help.

Up to now I just found something about the zeros of the polynomial $e(z) - f_N(z)$ (i.e. the truncated taylor expansion of $e(z)$). The keyword here is "Szegö curve".

Comment: Not mentioning the zero at z=0 and complex conjugates:

For N = 3 the smallest solution is 3.838602048 + 8.366815507 i.

For N = 4 the smallest solution is 5.439213999 + 9.129463691 i. 

For N = 5 the smallest solution is 6.952562475 + 9.800729397 i.

For N = 6 the smallest solution is 8.407369863 + 10.40707148 i.

for N = 7 the smallest solution is 8.28937986 + 8.687044071 i for N = 8 the smallest solution is 9.536388591 + 8.053389728 i but there is a smaller real solution at -9.773234001

Comment: Yes, I know, no problem to solve that numerically for fixed $N$.

Comment:  Yes, but I found them while trying to locate the zeros in general. There are an infinite number of zeros that run mainly on a line parallell to the imaginary axis. Of course these zeros are separated one of other approximately in 2 pi i. For example the function for N = 8 has zeros at the points 27.26763038 + 163.7377084 i, 27.52677947 + 170.0540751 i, 27.77668695 + 176.3684616 i, 28.01799005 + 182.6810464 i, 28.25126216 + 188.9919872 i, 28.47702109 + 195.301423 i.

Answer (score 6):

This is studied in the Appendix of the paper, Hassen and Nguyen, Hypergeometric zeta functions, available [here](http://www.rowan.edu/open/depts/math/NGUYEN/hypergeometriczetafunctions.pdf). Let $$T_N(z)=\sum_{k=0}^N{z^k\over k!}$$ and let $$z=x+iy=re^{i\theta}$$ be a root of $$e^z-T_N(z)=0$$ with $y\gt0$. They give an asymptotic approximation of the roots: $$x\sim N\log\bigl(2q\pi+(\pi/2)N-\log(N!)\bigr),\qquad y\sim(N!)^{1/N}e^{x/N}$$ I think "asymptotic" here means asymptotic in $r$, so this gives the big zeros, not the small ones that were requested. However, there is rather more in this appendix, and you may find something of use in it.

Answer (score 1):

See two surveys of I. V. Ostrovskii, on zeros of "tails" of power series,
MR1890545, MR1771769.